# Can't play 4K video in UIWebview in iOS

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview

I use UIWebView to load 4k Video.
But I can't play 4K video in some device:

> 1. Iphone 6 plus iOS 8.0.3: can't run
> 2. Iphone 5s iOS 9.0: can't run

I've tried to use WKWebview, but the same, WKWebview also can't play 4K video.
Who can help me?
Thank you.